# How would I go about identifying and matching this wood stain color?

Tags: woodworking, staining, wooden-furniture

I inherited some wooden furniture (which I believe to be oak) a few years back and was looking to add a couple of pieces to it. I want to try and get close to the same color, but I have no idea what color this actually is, so I was looking for some help. Sorry that some of the photos are a little more "blue" for some reason.

Photos are of the end-table and coffee-table.

[image: Coffee Table]
[image: End Table]

Answer (score 12):

Well first off: that's not oak. It's larch or southern yellow pine (maybe even hemlock) from the look of it. As for color, that looks very near to the natural color of softwood after some yellowing from age but its hard to say. It appears to be production grade furniture (although of a fairly high quality) which means the colorant(stain), if any, is a proprietary blend mixed specially for the manufacturer by a finish supplier (i.e. Sherwin Williams) so trying to track it down will be difficult or impossible. But don't desperate, most furniture makers have a "natural" color blend and most of them are very similar.

Comment: For matching stain the best bet is to get a sample piece of wood of the same type (maybe even use the back of one of the furniture pieces you have if it is unfinished) grab some half pints (the little tiny cans) and then try the base colors.  If they are off you can start mixing them together...just remember to keep track of the ratios.  Getting a custom match from your local paint store is also a good suggestion, I just like to play with it myself.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to have Sherwin-Williams do a stain match. The only thing I suggest otherwise is that when they ask you the wood type, you reply to them that you have white pine as that is what the furniture is. If I were trying to come close I would grab natural stain and satin polyurethane.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your local paint or big box store and get a color chart for the stains they carry. Often they show the stain on both oak and pine. As Veritas pointed out, you have pine.

Pick the colors that come close (recommend three: one as close as possible, one lighter, one darker) and buy the smallest can possible (usually a half pint). Test each of these on an inconspicuous area on the new pieces (also pine if you want them to look similar). Also put on a topcoat, which tends to make a stained surface look a little bit lighter. Pick the one that looks closest to the originals. Go back and buy enough to do the job.